# Global CSS stylesheet for NiceGUI

Tags: nicegui

Is there a way to provide a global CSS stylesheet?

I want to override underlying elements or configure all elements at once by my own css classes.

I know this style (`ui.label('label ').style('color: rgb(..`) syntax, but such configuration has to be repeated for every element.

Answer (score 2):

You can style the whole HTML `body` by using the `ui.query` to provide a global CSS stylesheet.

```py
ui.query('body').style('background-color: red')
ui.run()
```

You can find more about it on official documentation [here](https://nicegui.io/documentation#query_selector).

---

### Update 1:

If the CSS doesnt need to be assigned to the whole body, but selective elements only, we can append the elements to a common list while creating and assign the style together later on.

```py
from typing import List
from nicegui import ui
from nicegui.elements.label import Label   # importing for type comparison
from nicegui.elements.label import Button  # importing for type comparison

css_elements:List = []

label1 = ui.label('My Label 1')
css_elements.append(label1)
button1 = ui.button('My Button 1')
css_elements.append(button1)

# styling all elements together in a for loop
for element in css_elements:
    element.style('background-color: red')
   
    # We can also style based upon type of element
    if isinstance(element, Label):
        element.style('background-color: blue')
    elif isinstance(element, Button):
        element.style('background-color: green')
    else:
        element.style('background-color: red')

ui.run()
```

### Update 2:

As per niceGUI's creator's response [here](https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/discussions/1015#discussioncomment-6146190), to provide custom CSS, you can just add it as Head html using `ui.add_head_html` method.

```py
ui.add_head_html('''
<style>
.colored-radio div:nth-of-type(1) > .q-radio > .q-radio__inner--truthy {
  color: red !important;
}
.colored-radio div:nth-of-type(2) > .q-radio > .q-radio__inner--truthy {
    color: green !important;
}
.colored-radio div:nth-of-type(3) > .q-radio > .q-radio__inner--truthy {
    color: blue !important;
}
</style>
''')

ui.radio(['red', 'green', 'blue']).classes('colored-radio')
```

**OR**

You can reference using a CSS file as well.

```py
app.add_static_files('styles.css', 'styles.css')
ui.add_head_html('''<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">''')
```

Comment: This would style the single "body" element only. 

Maybe it would work to give some css child operators (`body > label`), but that's no nice solution.

Comment: Since you mentioned all elements, assigning css to `body` tag makes sense. But if you still want to do it selectively you can just put all of them in a global list when you create and assign the css by iterating over the list. Adding this as well in the answer.

Comment: Hmm, the solution provided in the UPDATE section was exactly what I was going to avoid! It's so scattered.  In a "normal" web project you have a more or less global style-sheet with some CSS classes in it. These CSS classes have to be assigned to your elements. That way you have a separation of code and design...

Comment: I see. Yeah I understand your concern now @rolo. Took time to wrap around what problem you were facing since I am not much of a frontend guy, Does the update 2 answers your concern?

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Unfortunately I cannot upvote - too less reputation.

Answer (score 2):

This answer above and from [Github](https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/discussions/1575) lead me to 2 solutions:

My favourite:

```py
# style-sheet file is: Path(__file__).parent / "static" / "styles.css"
# the root folder or single file was not working
app.add_static_files('/static', 'static')
ui.add_head_html('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles.css">')
```

or:

```py
ui.add_head_html("<style>" + open(Path(__file__).parent / "static" / "styles.css").read() + "</style>")
```