# add static css files to nicegui

Tags: css, nicegui

see also [Global CSS stylesheet for NiceGUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77043716/global-css-stylesheet-for-nicegui)

I have a bunch of local .css files i'd like to make available for ui.html() elements in nicegui. In justpy i used to do this  as

```py
  @self.app.route('/ceur-ws.css')
        def ceur_ws_css():
            return send_from_directory(f'{os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}/resources/css', "ceur-ws.css")

        @self.app.route('/ceur-ws-semantic.css')
        def ceur_ws_semantic_css():
            return send_from_directory(f'{os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}resources/css', 'ceur-ws-semantic.css')
```

What whould be the equivalent approach in nicegui? ther is e.g.

```py
app.add_static_files('/examples', 'examples')
```

as described in
https://nicegui.io/documentation/section_pages_routing

but that seems to force a new directory structure e.g. adding a "/css" to the links - since I want' to display contents in an iframe i don't have the option to modify the css access.

do I actually have to use

```py
ui.add_head_html("<style>" + open(Path(__file__).parent / "static" / "styles.css").read() + "</style>")
```

e.g. in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `app.add_static_file()` (singular) could solve your problem. Its only mentioned briefly [here](https://nicegui.io/documentation/section_pages_routing#add_a_directory_of_static_files_):

> To make a single file accessible, you can use `add_static_file()`.

We use it, e.g., to serve the NiceGUI logo on our website:

```py
app.add_static_file(local_file=svg.PATH / 'logo.png', url_path='/logo.png')
app.add_static_file(local_file=svg.PATH / 'logo_square.png', url_path='/logo_square.png')
```

https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/blob/d2f6cede439417cff5ff635e14db0c4ae8e20fb9/main.py#L23-L24